# Spatial Join with start and endpoints of polylines in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I want to join 2 layers. One of them is are polylines and has two pairs of lat/long, representing the start and the end.

```
id    lat_start    long_start    lat_end    lat_start
```

The other layer is a polygon with districts.

```
district
district1
district2
...
```

What I want to do is performing a spatial join two times:

1. with a district_start
2. with district_end

I want my final line-layer to look like this

```
id    lat_start    long_start    lat_end    lat_start    district_start    district_end
```

Of course, I already tried vector --> data management tools --> spatial join and MMQGIS but they don't have the result I want. Actually they even assign districts that never work with the start nor the end.